# Explanation of keras layers behavior in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I made an experiment but I cannot understand why I get that result:

1. I create and fit a simple model using functional API with 3 hidden layers:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

input_ = layers.Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1:]))
hidden1 = layers.Dense(30, activation='relu')(input_)
hidden2 = layers.Dense(30, activation='relu')(hidden1)
hidden3 = layers.Dense(30, activation='relu')(hidden2)
output = layers.Dense(1)(hidden3)
model1 = keras.Model(inputs=input_, outputs=output)
model1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
history = model1.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=200)
```

2. Now say I want to investigate the activation of the second hidden layer. I then create another model like this:

```
model2 = keras.Model(inputs=input_, outputs=hidden2)
```

Surprisingly for me if I now call `model2.weights` these weights are the same as  `model1.layers[2].weights` that has been fitted previously, but I never call `.fit()` on `model2`.

This led me to think that the layer weights must be stored in the `hidden2` object after I call `model1.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=200)`, so when I define `model2 = keras.Model(inputs=input_, outputs=hidden2)` it already knows the weights.

But when I try to investigate the `hidden2` object I could not find any way to extract the weights.

Hence my question is how is it possible that `model2` knows the weights of the `model1` if they are not contained in the `hidden2` object?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Functional API, and this is exactly the intended behavior. This API can be used to share weights between layer instances (tensors).

What is happening is that the layer (`layers.Dense(30, activation='relu')`) is the one that stores the layers, and when you generate new tensors (by calling `Model(....)`), the weights are reused as you are reusing the actual layers in the model.

If you want for the layer to have new weights, then you should create new layers, not reuse the ones in the model. Otherwise, it is working fine.